# Flask context and python-rq

Tags: flask, task-queue

I have a Flask application with blueprints that is structured like this:

```
application.py
project/
    form_emailer.py
    blueprints/
        example_form.py
    wtforms-models/
        example_form_model.py
    templates/
        example_form_template.html
```

I'm trying to use RQ to send emails in the background (using [Flask-Mail](http://pythonhosted.org/flask-mail/)) because our SMTP uses the Gmail servers, which can take a few seconds to complete. My function in form_emailer.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message
from application import app, q

mail = Mail(app)

def _queue_message(message):
    mail.send(message)

def sendemail(recipients, subject, body):
    """
    This function gets called in a Flask blueprint.
    """
    message = Message(recipients=recipients, subject=subject, body=body)
    q.enqueue(_queue_message, message)
```

My (simplified) application.py looks like this. I'm breaking convention by using "import *" in order to simplify additions there (our __init__.py in those packages dynamically import all modules):

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue

app = Flask(__name__)

q = Queue(connection=Redis())

from project.blueprints import *
from project.forms import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have an rqworker running in the same virtual environment where my application is running, and the worker detects the task. However, I'm getting the following traceback and can't figure out how to fix this:

```
16:41:29 *** Listening on high, normal, low...
16:43:26 low: project.form_emailer._queue_message(<flask_mail.Message object at 0x299d690>) (bd913b3a-4e7f-4efb-b51c-8ae11d37ac00)
16:43:27 ImportError: cannot import name sendemail
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "./project/blueprints/example_form.py", line 4, in <module>
  from project.form_emailer import sendemail
ImportError: cannot import name sendemail
```

I suspect this has to do with Flask's application context, but my initial attempts to use `with app.app_context():` are failing; the worker is not even able to import the function I want to use. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is completely irrelevant, but: we too were having problems with attempting to send e-mail from the web server to a slow mail server, and solved the problem by [installing exim](1) in smarthost mode. Basically, exim is our mail server according to Flask, and it will quickly accept the e-mails from the mail server, then queue them up to send off to the mail server. Just something to look into so that you don't need to code something custom just to deal with a slow mail server.

Comment: Also, does application.py (or one of the modules it imports) at all try to import form_emailer.py? You might have a circular reference.

Comment: Also, apparently I screwed up the link above: should be to [here](https://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4).

Comment: @MarkHildreth Yes, I'm importing form_emailer.py in my application.py, among other things, which do create circular dependencies. I may be confusing advice in the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/#working-with-blueprints)

Comment: Please update your question with your application.py (or at least the parts where you are doing imports).

Comment: Try putting everything from `application.py` into `project/__init__.py`, except for when you actually do `app.run()`. Then, in `application.py`, import `app` and do the `app.run()`. Also, anywhere you input `app` or `rq`, import from `project` rather than `application`.